# Missing HTML comments in JSP page

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, comments

I am writing a web app using Spring Roo hosted in a Tomcat 6/7server.

I have added HTML comments into the *.jspx pages however they are not being sent to the client browser. It's as if they are being stripped out...

E.g.

```
<div><!-- comment --></div>
```

Results in at the browser as an empty div.

Is there a setting in tomcat or jsp directive/spring to enable or disable HTML comments?

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you use firebug, right?
In firebug is on option to deactivate comments, I had the same problem.

If you activate the view of comments in firebug, you will see all comments like  in the client view.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use

```
       <!-- Output comment>
```

This is for hidden Comment which will not render in browser.

```
       <!-- Hidden comment -->
```